# get Element multiple ID or CLASS

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I can't make javascript to get more than one element with the class I specify.. I'm using classes on purpose!! If I have 5 divs with the same class, how should I call them?

```
onmouseover="document.getElementById('logo').style.display='inline';" 
onmouseout="document.getElementById('logo').style.display='none';"

onmouseover="document.getElementsByClassName('new')[0].style.MozOpacity=0.4;" 
onmouseout="document.getElementsByClassName('new')[0].style.MozOpacity=1;"
```

And can I make something like : `.getElementsByClassName('new,new2,new3')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to use [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page), I would highly recommend it, it makes such things trivial:

```
$('#idOfYourElement')
  .mouseenter(function() { $('.new, .new2, .new3').css({MozOpacity : 0.4});)
  .mouseleave(function() { $('.new, .new2, .new3').css({MozOpacity : 1}););
```

Answer (score 3):

> I can't make javascript to get more than one element with the class I specify

`getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList. Just loop over it instead of accessing `[0]`, which is the first element in it.

> And can I make something like: `.getElementsByClassName('new,new2,new3')`

Yes, you can write a function that calls `getElementsByClassName` multiple times and then aggregates the results.

All the major JS libraries include CSS selector engines and there are [more than a few dedicated libraries for that purpose](http://microjs.com/#css). You can pass a [group](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#grouping) of class selectors to one of them.

Comment: maybe I went wrong with "loop over".. Jqueryseemed faster, but am I missing something to this? ' $(document).ready(function(){ $(".lazio #sar").hover(function(){ $(".lazio").animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow") return false; }); }); '

Answer (score 0):

```
[].forEach.call( document.getElementsByClassName('new'), function( elem ) {
elem.style.MozOpacity = 1;
});
```